# Any convex and closed set in R has to be a closed interval of the form [a,b]

Tags: convex-analysis

**Prove or Disprove**

*Any convex and closed set in R has to be a closed interval of the form [a,b]*

I initially thought that R itself is convex and closed and not in this form. So, counter-example.

But then I realized that R is also open, that is to say R is a clopen set. Then this approach may fail, right?

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb R$ is a counterexample. It does not matter that $\mathbb R$ is also open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any *bounded* convex closed set has to be a closed interval of the form $[a,b]$ (proof: let $a$ be the infimum of the set and $b$ the supremum; bounded implies both are in $\mathbb R$; closure implies both are in the set; convex implies every point inside the interval is too).

As you say, unbounded sets such as $\mathbb R$ itself are not of this form - if you want an example which is not open then $[a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, b]$ will do.